# Maven failsafe plugin and spring unable to load beans

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm trying to run a simple Integration test with spring support, with mave failsafe plugin. As it seems failsafe plugin seems that it does not respect the ContextConfiguration as expected therefore it is unable to find the relevant beans for dependency injection. More specifically I have the following simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:test-context.xml"})
public class MyIntegrationJUnitIT {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean bean;

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
       // logic
    }
}
```

Inside my test-context i declare the bean "MyBean"

My failsafe plugin as in many sites demonstrate is the following:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven.failsafe.plugin}</version>
<configuration>
    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that when i try to execute this in the following way it fails:

```
mvn clean verify
```

When I run it as a simple JUnit test it works fine

What am I missing?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The test-context is empty, it is for future usage it just contain my example bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean name="myBean" class="com.thomas.MyBean"/> 

</beans>
```

My failsafe plugin version is 2.17

Error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger     
(org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Running com.thomas.test.MyIntegrationJUnitIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.377 sec <<< FAILURE! -   in com.thomas.test.MyIntegrationJUnitIT
myTest(com.thomas.test.MyIntegrationJUnitIT)  Time elapsed: 0.373 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'com.thomas.test.MyIntegrationJUnitIT': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested     exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire     field: private com.thomas.test.MyBean; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type    [com.thomas.test.MyBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as    autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:  {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:376)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:113)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Results :

Tests in error: 
  MyIntegrationJUnitIT.myTest » BeanCreation Error creating bean with name 'c...

  Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Please paste the error and `test-context.xml`.

Comment: I have edited and added the error, seems pretty basic exception. It cannot find the relevant bean, event if it is in the text context, any ideas?

Comment: It seems that it ignores the ContextConfiguration annotation completely

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have managed to figure out what is the problem, I explain it in brief if someone finds it interesting

the case was that I had a separate module in my structure and I had to declare specifically resource and testResource tag to be able to grab the xml files and for ContextConfiguration to be able to load the application context i was declaring to. The tricky part was that the error was not about the file not being present but that it was unable to autowire property the beans I was injecting. Hope it helps

Thomas